# R error at the start of Android project

Tags: android, file

I have started a new application project in android and I am getting this strange error on R file.I have done many projects but this is for the first time that an R error is coming as R file is generated automatically.There is no error in my xml or class files as I have just started the project.This is what its showing-:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
R cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

I tried creating the R class but it shows up in src folder and not in gen folder.Please help me out here anyone.Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your project R.java file is not created due to any error in your any xml file. I'm correct??

Comment: You made angry to android's *HULK* (R.java) :D

Comment: Thanks yugesh...that thought didn't cross my mind at all..silly me..thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete **R.java** file from your source folder. Now **Clean** your project

and also try this.

Right Click on your **Projectname** >> **Android Tools** >> **Fix project Property**

Answer (score 1):

Check your Java compiler version, it should be 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Clean and build your project. This will generate R.java to you auto generated files folder.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your R.java which is created under your src directory and then do clean and build.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project of course but if you any imported lib  like xxx.R  delete

Answer (score 1):

Check the problems tab in eclipse IDE, it must be showing some errors.

otherwise clean and build.

Also check Build Automatically option in project menu.

Comment: Open problems tab like this if its not open = Window->Show View->Problems